# Converting annual rates to daily probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Good afternoon,

I am trying to convert annual reported rates to daily probabilities. However, I have annual rates that only occur during certain months of the year. For example, I have an annual mortality rate of 0.72 and this rate needs to be converted to a daily probability of mortality across only 4 months (120 days).

Is this equation simply: 1 - [(1-Annual Rate)^(1/120)] ?
And/or the equivalent: 1-exp((1/365)log(1-Annual Rate)) ?

The '120' would normally be 365 to convert an annual rate to a daily probability. Can I simply exchange '365' for the relevant timespan (i.e., number of days) for each rate?

Thank you in advance.